# How to show query parameter options in Django REST Framework - Swagger

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

This has been bugging me for a while now.

My ultimate goal is to show query parameter options inside SwaggerUI and give a form input for each query parameter. Similar to how it is displayed when providing a serializer for POST.

I am using a viewset which inherits from GenericViewSet and I have tried the following:

- provide `filter_fields` attribute
- provide and set `filter_backends` attribute to `(filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)`
- provide filter_class defined inside my module.
- Override `options` method to provide `[actions][GET]` information

Here's a small catch, I am not using any models so I don't think DjangoFilterBackend will really help me.  I am using DjangoRESTFramework to talk to an outside API, and I am simply getting JSON result back, and passing it through to the frontend layer.

Here is a small modified snippet of my code to better explain my problem:

views.py

```
class SomeViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    # Note that I have all of these defined, but I have tried various combinations
    filter_fields = ('query_option_1', 'query_option_2',)
    filter_backeds = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = SomeFilter
    query_metadata = some_dict

    # This works when request is OPTIONS
    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.metadata_class is None:
            return self.http_method_not_allowed(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data = self.metadata_class().determine_metadata(request, self)
        data['actions']['GET'] = self.query_metadata
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

filters.py

```
class SomeFilter(FilterSet):
    strict = True
    query_option_1 = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='query_option_1')
    query_option_2 = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='query_option_2')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['query_option_1', 'query_option_2']
```

Thank you for looking, and thanks in advance for responding.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay, for those who stumble upon this question, I have figured it out. It is rather silly, and I feel a little stupid for not knowing, but in my defense, it was not clearly documented. The information was not found in DRF documentation, or inside Django REST Swagger repository. Instead it was found under django-rest-framework-docs, which is what Django REST Swagger is built off of.

To specify your query parameter to show up in your SwaggerUI as a form field, you simply comment like so:

```
def list(self):
    """
    param1 -- A first parameter
    param2 -- A second parameter
    """ 
    ...
```

And swagger will parse your comments and will put a form input for param1 and param2. What follows `--` are the descriptions for the parameters.

Comment: I tried your solution but the query parameters do not show up neither for the default HTML API documentation nor for [*rest_framework_swagger*](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/).

Comment: **NOTE** This works for swagger but not for rest_framework_docs

Comment: @dnit13 There is markdown support in DRF docs, but not released yet,   pepole can still use it with a custom templatetag and a template override.
https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-docs/pull/127/files#diff-22988fe5403ab4a34d522ff6fb4bb436

Comment: @dnit13 Do you know of a way to get this functionality through DRF docs?

Comment: For Django rest swagger 2+, use vadimchin answer

Answer (score 39):

New swagger

```
from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend
import coreapi

class SimpleFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        return [coreapi.Field(
            name='query',
            location='query',
            required=False,
            type='string'
        )]

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    filter_backends = (SimpleFilterBackend,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # print(request.GET.get('query'))  # Use the query param in your view
        return Response({'hello': 'world'}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: In Django rest swagger 2 this is the relevant answer, since docstrings are deprecated.

Comment: I had to add a method `filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view)` that does nothing because teh `BaseFilterBackend` will raise `NotImplementedError` when it tries to filter the queryset.

Comment: @jarussi you need to import BaseFilterBackend  ```from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend``` should do the work. You also need ```pip install coreapi```. Thanks @vadimchin, worked for me.

Comment: How do I do this for adding option GET parameters to function based api views?

Answer (score 14):

I found the [rest framework swagger docs](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/yaml.html).
so we can write the parameter type(interger, char), response, etc.

the tripple `---` is necessary.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def foo_view(request):
    """
    Your docs
    ---
    # YAML (must be separated by `---`)

    type:
      name:
        required: true
        type: string
      url:
        required: false
        type: url
      created_at:
        required: true
        type: string
        format: date-time

    serializer: .serializers.FooSerializer
    omit_serializer: false

    parameters_strategy: merge
    omit_parameters:
        - path
    parameters:
        - name: name
          description: Foobar long description goes here
          required: true
          type: string
          paramType: form
        - name: other_foo
          paramType: query
        - name: other_bar
          paramType: query
        - name: avatar
          type: file

    responseMessages:
        - code: 401
          message: Not authenticated
    """
```

How about the situation we use the mixins class such as `ModelViewSets`.
Do we need to define the `list` function just to add the docs? 
-- No

We can do like this:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    Articles.
    ---
    list:    #<--- here!!
        parameters:
            - name: name
              description: article title
    get_price:
        omit_serializer: true

    """

    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def get_price(self, request):
        pass
```

Comment: FYI, there's a bug in django-rest-swagger==0.3.4, check https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/303 . you should replace `list` with HTTP method names such as `GET` in your example.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`@swagger_auto_schema()`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) to indicate any additional query parameters. Define the parameters through either:

- [`manual_parameters`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.utils.swagger_auto_schema)
- or [`query_serializer`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.utils.swagger_auto_schema)

Example:

```py
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema


class SomeViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        query_serializer=MyQueryParamSerializer,
        manual_parameters=[
            openapi.Parameter(
                'my_new_query_param',
                openapi.IN_QUERY,
                description="The new query param",
                type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
            ),
            openapi.Parameter(
                'my_other_query_param',
                openapi.IN_QUERY,
                description="Another query param",
                type=openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            )
        ],
    )
    def list(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ...

...

class MyQueryParamSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_name = serializers.CharField()
    my_number = serializers.IntegerField(help_text="Some custom description for the number")
    my_bool = serializers.BooleanField()
```

Screenshot of swagger with the custom added query parameters along with the others:

[image]

Triggered request contains the query params in the URL:

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/the_path/?page=3&size=2&my_name=Taguro&my_number=100&my_bool=false&my_new_query_param=120%20percent!!!&my_other_query_param=true' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Sample usages from documentation:

```py
@swagger_auto_schema(method='get', manual_parameters=[test_param], responses={200: user_response})
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'])
def user_detail(request, pk):
    ...
```

```py
class UserList(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: UserSerializer(many=True)})
    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Working with openapi (and not coreapi), the "simplest" way I found is from this [core dev comment](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6992#issuecomment-541711632):

```py
from rest_framework.schemas.openapi import AutoSchema


class CustomSchema(AutoSchema):
    def get_operation(self, path, method):
        op = super().get_operation(path, method)
        op['parameters'].append({
            "name": "foo",
            "in": "query",
            "required": True,
            "description": "What foo does...",
            'schema': {'type': 'string'}
        })
        return op


class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    schema = CustomSchema()

    def get_queryset(self):
        foo = self.request.query_params.get("foo")
        if foo:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(foo=foo)
        return self.queryset
```

Comment: Is this still the "simplest" way? :)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am using `django_filters`, so results may vary. `django_filters` uses the param `filter_fields` in the DRF ViewSet, which may be different than not using `django_filters`.

I took inspiration from [this thread](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/549#issuecomment-324537814) and overrode the `get_schema_fields()` method in the filtering backend in the following way.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('location.of.custom_backend.CustomDjangoFilterBackend')
    ...
}
```

custom_backend.py

```
import coreapi
import coreschema
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


class CustomDjangoFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    """
    Overrides get_schema_fields() to show filter_fields in Swagger.
    """

    def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        assert (
            coreapi is not None
        ), "coreapi must be installed to use `get_schema_fields()`"
        assert (
            coreschema is not None
        ), "coreschema must be installed to use `get_schema_fields()`"

        # append filter fields to existing fields
        fields = super().get_schema_fields(view)
        if hasattr(view, "filter_fields"):
            fields += view.filter_fields

        return [
            coreapi.Field(
                name=field,
                location='query',
                required=False,
                type='string',
            ) for field in fields
        ]
```

Comment: I've discovered another little trick. You can derive the field's actual type from the model and tie it to the `coreapi.Field` `type` using `type=view.serializer_class.Meta.model._meta.get_field(field).get_internal_type()` if you want it to reflect the actual field type instead of showing it in the Swagger docs as the default 'string'.

Answer (score 2):

If the query parameters are used in a filter backend, adding a `get_schema_operation_parameters` method is the simplest solution:

```
class SimpleFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        foo = request.query_params.get("foo")
        if foo:
            queryset = queryset.filter(foo=foo)
        return queryset

    def get_schema_operation_parameters(self, view):
        return [{
            "name": "foo",
            "in": "query",
            "required": True,
            "description": "What foo does...",
            "schema": {"type": "string"}
        }]

class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [SimpleFilterBackend]
```

Comment: This worked for me while the top rated answer and accepted answer did not. DRF 3.12.4

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this later, I pieced together a few solutions and came up with this:

This is using the new `openapi` instead of `coreapi`.

I subclassed `AutoSchema` to accept a dictionary keyed on action name and mapping to the OpenApi Operation Parameter object spec. These params get appended to the operation.

```
from rest_framework.schemas.openapi import AutoSchema

class ParameterSchema(AutoSchema):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.parameters = kwargs.pop("parameters")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_operation(self, path, method):
        op = super().get_operation(path, method)
        method_name = getattr(self.view, "action", method.lower())
        action_parameters = self.parameters.get(method_name, [])
        for param in action_parameters:
            op["parameters"].append(param)
        return op


class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    schema = ParameterSchema(
        parameters={
            "list": [
                {
                    "name": "my-param",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": False,
                    "description": "Description on the param",
                    "schema": {"type": "boolean", "default": False},
                }
            ]
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the answers above from @vadimchin - here is a working example.

```
# requirements.txt

djangorestframework==3.9.3
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
django==2.2.1
coreapi==2.3.3
```

I am using Viewsets in my application. I had to implement `filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view)` as suggested by @jarussi.

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models 

class Recording(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=511)
```

```py
# serializers.py

from models import Recording
from rest_framework import serializers

class RecordingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recording
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
# views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets
from filters import NameFilterBackend
from serializers import RecordingSerializer

class RecordingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RecordingSerializer
    queryset = Recording.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (NameFilterBackend,)
```

```py
# filters.py 

from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend
import coreapi

class NameFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        return [coreapi.Field(
            name='name',
            location='query',
            required=False,
            type='string',
            description='name of recording'
        )]

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        try:
            n = request.query_params['name']
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=n)
        except KeyError:
            # no query parameters
            pass
        return queryset
```

Comment: Hi sir, can we use this on detailed routes?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [this github issue](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/604) which solves the problem.