# parameters not showing up in swagger-ui django

Tags: python, django, parameters, swagger-ui

I am trying to show APIs on swagger-ui in Django but for some reason, parameters are not showing up. I am attaching the snippet for a clear view.

[image]

Code is as follows in which I am using 3 variables:

```
def myfunc(request):
    fromDate = request.GET['fromDate']
    toDate = request.GET['toDate']
    dealershipId = request.GET['dealershipId']

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("exec proc_LoadJobCardbyDateRange @Fromdate='"+fromDate+"', @Todate='"+toDate+"', @DealershipId="+dealershipId)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    data = {
        'message': 'Data Retrieved Successfully',
        'job_card': result
    }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Also, I am not using any serializer or models here. May be that's why parameters are not showing up as it's not linking with any model or serializer but I am new to do this so I don't know. Please help so I can show parameters in the swagger-ui.

Comment: please chekout this soluation:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203070/how-to-show-query-parameter-options-in-django-rest-framework-swagger